# using ssh-agent to ssh into a remote server without typing the password

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I am trying to use `ssh-agent` to `ssh` into a remote-server.

I understand that when I add my localhost's `public_key` to the remote-server's `./ssh/authorized_keys`, I can ssh into the server without typing my password.

However, I tried to do it using `ssh-agent` because I need to `ssh` into a remote server in my Jenkins pipeline. Before doing it on Jenkins, I tried to do it locally.

What I did is

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
chmod 600 ./key_key2.key
ssh-add ./key_key2.key
ssh root@<remote_server> docker ps -v
```

where `key_key2.key` contains the `private_key` of the remote-server.

This still makes me type the password. Is this the correct way to do it?

I feel like using `ssh-agent` is skipping the part where I add the `public_key` to the remote-server's `authorized_keys`, but I thought to skip that part was one of the points of using the `public_key`.

Comment: when you created the private/public key pair did you input a password? if so, this is why is prompting for a password. Also, you NEVER move the private key from the server.

Comment: @HeysusEscobar Thanks for the reply. No, I didn't input a password. Also, if I am doing this on Jenkins, how am I supposed to pass the public key to the remote server if I am not able to `ssh` in the first place?

Comment: From my experience you can say to remote server and paste the public key or have physical access to the server and insert a USB with the public key and copy/paste to authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume ServerA is your computer at home and ServerB is the remote server. In order to connect via public/private key, we need to create a set of keys on ServerA. Please note that I did not enter a password.

```
ServerA $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:11tmtkpYjGCPLc8I59kV1QySEYfwpJt76BDMX01aTkU admin@localhost
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|          ..==+=E|
|           +o+ .o|
|        o . o +  |
|       + = * O   |
|      . S B B B  |
|       + @ B * . |
|        = O + .  |
|         o o .   |
|          . .    |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

As you can see the keys were generated at /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa(private key) and /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub(public key).

Now, we log onto ServerB and add the public key from ServerA to the authorized_keys located in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

```
ServerA $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDP4BIiaHUm6Ow9SGFOdHpsaAu2odnBLfDu5YjwQeESLe7ubfQ62v21PXKAJUVS0ZcAN7KfAfHv+f8Los8GE7NhAJUeOB18YpaQohLVaajKb0pSJnAfcYMqH38Ouq3Q23GA61ZqUF4o3pJpRf9O2V/qpIkGQtMZ1/EbYApvh0y+MSlmrDHNjm6n6LO1P31WqsAwzTlZilcaDJTDu3ILW+bd+b1LzMr2oQUPnrc2YIiGRt8PvvM5YcGfN9/4D1vKyLNgF3c+KhbEapsoxfsGmEl1Z+jR/ldep0jwEh7XVXAMrLWhtUdi/a40R0Zisj3b27gfrQLmEMBOS4X0nfDJ9/QoxVl16SwZWxFuDX1xV/n2XIAg1OQ== admin@localhost
```

Copy an paste the output of ServerA into ServerB authorized_keys.

```
ServerB $ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDP4BIiaHUm6Ow9SGFOdHpsaAu2odnBLfDu5YjwQeESLe7ubfQ62v21PXKAJUVS0ZcAN7KfAfHv+f8Los8GE7NhAJUeOB18YpaQohLVaajKb0pSJnAfcYMqH38Ouq3Q23GA61ZqUF4o3pJpRf9O2V/qpIkGQtMZ1/EbYApvh0y+MSlmrDHNjm6n6LO1P31WqsAwzTlZilcaDJTDu3ILW+bd+b1LzMr2oQUPnrc2YIiGRt8PvvM5YcGfN9/4D1vKyLNgF3c+KhbEapsoxfsGmEl1Z+jR/ldep0jwEh7XVXAMrLWhtUdi/a40R0Zisj3b27gfrQLmEMBOS4X0nfDJ9/QoxVl16SwZWxFuDX1xV/n2XIAg1OQ== admin@localhost
```

Now load the ssh-agent on serverA and add the private key

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ServerA $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa)

ServerA $ ssh admin@someip.com
The authenticity of host '[someIP.com]:2220 ([xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:2220)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:K6nMI2Dxb7t6oj00HlKmPCCuGorgQoBJCeXB31B9VTY.
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:aa:20:4f:08:bb:5d:c5:8e:fd:cb:4c:5f:b9:3b:44:59.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[someIP.com]:2220 ([xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:2220)' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Tue Nov 26 21:20:14 2019
admin@mail ~]$
```

Comment: What is the point of `ssh-add`ing at the end? I was still able to do it without adding that to the agent. Does that make any difference?